# Is it possible to get Admin API Access for the Garden FI?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We are developing a multi-tenant Banno plugin, and need access to the Admin API to verify and test the functionality available.

I've read through the Admin API documentation, including the Authentication and Tokens section at https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/overview/authentication/tokens/ where it appears to indicate that when using the jackhenry.dev portal and the Garden test institution, the Admin API is not accessible.

Is there a way to request access to this Admin API for the Garden test institution? If not, how do you suggest we test and verify the various Admin API's?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't offer access to the Admin API via the JackHenry.Dev developer dashboard nor the *Garden* demo institution.

You'll have to work with the back office administrator at a financial institution to gain access to the Admin API in their environment. They can work with you to provision access.